# Open source tool similar to MetadataTouch or metadata assistant?

Tags: opensource-projects

I am looking for a tool that is open source and similar to metadata touch or metadata assistant. If there isn't one I may create one.

Comment: I always check [AlternativeTo.net](http://alternativeto.net) for these kind of things. It's not 100% complete but it often turns up good ideas. In [this case I don't see any open-source alternatives listed](http://alternativeto.net/software/metadatatouch/).

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you need? Edit office document meta data? Fill in movie data from IMDB? Tag artists in MP3's? There might be specific linux tools that would do your job rather than a one-size-fits-all-mega-program.

Comment: @caleb that's why I posted here because alternativeto didn't have anything. I do use more specific tools to edit certain tags, but I am curious if there is something more 'monolithic' that supports many file types that is open source